# Find pd.DataFrame cell that has the value of None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
index  A        B
0      apple    bear
0      axis     None
0      ant      None
0      avocado  None
```

and my goal is to simple drop those row if they have `None` in the B column.

I tried `df[df['B'] != None]` but pandas returns me the exact same DataFrame without deleting the rows. And `df[df['B'] == None]` gives only an empty DataFrame.

Is this the correct way of trying to match the None value? I am not sure what is going on but `test = None` and then `test == None` works fine (returns True). Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df.dropna(subset=["B"])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea! It's close but as I just found out: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html, `Pandas/numpy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan`, does that mean any Boolean method will fail in this case...?

Comment: well , you can also try with this:  **df['B'].isnull()**

Comment: oh wait, i think I must have mistaken something wrong, it actually works! Thanks for the tips! The `isnull` I tried but it just says True to all the values somehow...